# Javascript Get Key from data (not showing key)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have some data which looks like this:

```
var mydata =[{
    "493":{
        "name":"Name 1",
        "subhere":{
            "subhere1":2
        }
    },
    "673":{
        "name":"Name 2",
        "subhere":{
            "subhere1":20
        }
    }
}];
```

I want to get the keys value into a variable so I’ve done this:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {       
    var obj = mydata[i];     
    for(var key in obj){
        var newObj = {      
            name: obj[key].name,
            y: obj[key].subhere.subhere1,
            id: i,
            test: obj[key]   
        };
        data.push(newObj);      
    }
}
```

If you look at the line that has `test: obj[key]` that’s the line I want to get the value of the key BUT when I `console.log(this.test)` I get `Object { name="Name 1",…etc` but it’s not giving me the `493` or `673`

How can I get the key number?

Comment: you can conver string into integer using `parseInt`

Comment: `for(var key in obj)` which means that you are grabbing `key` in `obj` which means that `key` will be the object property (`493`,`673`) and `obj[key]` will be the value (`Object { name="Name 1", ...etc`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you look at the line that has “test: obj[key]” that’s the line I
>   want to get the value of the key BUT when I console.log(this.test) I
>   get “Object { name=“Name 1”,…etc” but it’s not giving me the “493” or
>   “673”

Simply replace

```
  test: obj[key]
```

with

```
   test: key
```

Since you are already having the key in variable `key`